# How to use CRC exactly?

Tags: javascript, node.js, crc, crc32

I've read the famous article [A PAINLESS GUIDE TO CRC ERROR DETECTION ALGORITHMS](http://www.repairfaq.org/filipg/LINK/F_crc_v31.html), now I want to try this out. I'm using a nodejs module [node-crc](https://github.com/alexgorbatchev/node-crc), it looks easy to use:

```
var crc = require('crc');

crc.crc32('hello');
# => "3610a686"
```

The result of function `crc32`, I believe, is the checksum of `hello` using polynomial `0x04C11DB7`. Please correct me if I' wrong.

So the next step is appending the checksum to the original data. Here's my code:

```
var crc = require('crc');

var bf = Buffer("test");

charlist = crc.crc32(bf).toString();
var k = []
for (var i=0; i< 8; i++) {
    k.push(parseInt(charlist[i], 16));
}
console.log(k)
var checksum = Buffer(k);    
console.log(crc.crc32(Buffer.concat([bf, checksum])));
```

**output**

```
[ 13, 8, 7, 15, 7, 14, 0, 12 ]
646b4f9b
```

I'm expecting the second output to be `0`, but it's not.
Therefore I'm here asking for help. What is the correct way to do this(appending and checking if the message was correctly received)? Thank you.

### **Edit**

So I understand that the second output isn't necessarilly `0`. Here's the final solution:

```
var crc = require('crc');

var bf = Buffer("test");

charlist = crc.crc32(bf).toString();
var k = []
for (var i=0; i< 8; i++) {
    k.push(parseInt(charlist[i], 16));
}
var checksum = Buffer(k);

transfer_data = Buffer.concat([bf, checksum]);

////////////////////// Network Transfer /////////////////////////

received_data = transfer_data

checksum = received_data.slice(-8);
charlist = '';
for (var i=0; i<8; i++) {
    charlist += checksum.readUInt8(i).toString(16);
}

// these two should be equal if data received correctly
console.log(crc.crc32(received_data.slice(0, -8)));
console.log(charlist)
```

Output

```
d87f7e0c
d87f7e0c
```

Comment: _"I'm expecting the second output to be 0"_ Why's that?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit From http://www.cs.jhu.edu/~scheideler/courses/600.344_S02/CRC.html, `When a message is received the corresponding polynomial is divided by G(x). If the remainder is non-zero, an error is detected. Otherwise, the message is assumed to be correct.`

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I was wrong, I know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the `crc32` function uses the polynomial you quoted, but it also is pre and post processed by taking the one's complement.  That eliminates the property that the (pure) CRC of a message with its CRC appended is zero.

The correct way to check a CRC, which is extensible to any manner of check value, is to simply compute the specified check algorithm on the message, and then compare the result with the check value appended to the message.

Comment: Thank you for help, but I still want to know if, theoretically, the second output is zero.

Comment: I answered that.  No.  This CRC does not have that property.

Comment: But according to http://www.cs.jhu.edu/~scheideler/courses/600.344_S02/CRC.html: `When a message is received the corresponding polynomial is divided by G(x). If the remainder is non-zero, an error is detected. Otherwise, the message is assumed to be correct.`. I'm confused.

Comment: That is true for a CRC with no pre or post-processing.  This is not that.

Comment: Got it. Since most articles only talk about pure CRC, I'm unware of post/pre processing, nor can I find useful meterials to read. Anyway, thank you. I'll accept your answer soon.

Comment: It is covered in Chapter 14 of the very tutorial you linked.

Comment: The augmented message (which is your original message + the crc bytes) will produce the "residue" defined by the algo parameters, and the "residue" is not always 0. this residue then goes through the xorout stage. The xorout stage xors the residue with a constant defined by the particular algorithm. You can see some examples in the [CRC Catalog](https://reveng.sourceforge.io/crc-catalogue/16.htm). CRC16 IBM-SDLC, for instance has a residue of 0xf0b8 and a xorout of 0xffff. To make your code work against different CRC implementations, it's best to just comparing the CRC with what you expect.